# Site icons in the list and in HNQ are shuffled

Tags: bug, status-completed

This is what I'm seeing in my site selector, doesn't look right to me.

(Note that it's broken on SO, but not on the meta.)

Windows 7 x64, Chrome 59.0.3071.115, no user scripts. The cache was cleared, can repro with all extensions disabled.

[image: _]

Comment: Browser and version? Any scripts, plugins, or extensions running? Does this happen on other browsers on the same machine? No repro, WIndows 7 latest Chrome

Comment: What browser, system are you using? Any user scripts installed?

Comment: @Kendra Edited the info into the post.

Comment: If you open the dev-console any errors? No repro for me on Chrome/Win 10

Comment: @rene No, nothing. (Only those caused by an adblocker, disabling it removes the messages, but not the bug.)

Comment: This is something on our end - old sprite still in cache somewhere.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How about now?

Comment: @AdamLear Nothing, still the same thing. (Cleared my cache just in case again.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Try a hard refresh?

Comment: @AdamLear Nope, didn't help.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How about now?

Comment: This happens to me as well with Firefox 54 and Chrome 60.

Comment: I've discussed the problem [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39188872#39188872). It still persists, but the version of the spritesheet I get is [this](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=0b5182b5ddfc) (doesn't have the Augur icon) but if I remove ?v= from the URL it has the new Augur icon. My geographic location is Finland.

Comment: @AdamLear ping in case you didn't get notification

Comment: Update: now it's fixed for me

Comment: similar problem report at MSE: [Wrong icons in the “hot network questions” column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299205/165773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug seems to be fixed.

<sup>I'll accept my answer when I'll be able to. I someone posts an answer explaining what happened, I'll accept it instead.</sup>

Comment: For me, it is not fixed.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Did you try clearing the cache or doing a hard refresh?