# Wrong icon for Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug

The icon for meta on the main site seems to be wrong:

[image]

The icon shown on meta is correct though. What's up?

There's a similar problem here: [Site icons in the list and in HNQ are shuffled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354332/site-icons-in-the-list-and-in-hnq-are-shuffled) but it has been resolved for the asker, but my issue still remains.

Comment: The marked duplicate seems to be solved for the OP, but for me it still happens. Voted for reopening.