# I'm seeing the wrong site icons in my profile page

Tags: bug, design

I'm seeing the wrong icons for the meta and network sites on my profile page:

[image]

Seems similar to this issue from a while back:

[Site icons in the list and in HNQ are shuffled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354332/site-icons-in-the-list-and-in-hnq-are-shuffled)

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374126/hot-network-questions-have-broken-icons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that is issue comes from the same source as [in the post that rene linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374126/hot-network-questions-have-broken-icons).

[Adam Lear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/105971/adam-lear) states the following in his answer there:

> This happens sometimes when we roll out a new set of icons due to how our build process works. I'll see what I can do about kicking the affected cachebreakers, but either way it'll resolve itself ... eventually. Caching is fun!

So this issue should get solved by itself as soon as caches are invalidated/rebuilt.

Comment: Yep no longer an issue for me