# Wrong site icon appearing in my inbox and profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've stumbled upon this issue a few minutes ago when accessing the site home page.

I'm using the new Dark Mode theme from SO and AFAIK it's not a bug for that since I've changed to the default theme and it persists.

Related question, but old: [I'm seeing the wrong site icons in my profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374128/7395911)

As pointed out [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/374202/7395911) this is a matter of caching, however it persisted after I disabled browser caching.

[image: Inbox]

[image: Profile page]

[image: Profile page default theme]

Comment: I cannot repro. I am not using dark mode.

Comment: How about now? We launched a site earlier and I got sidetracked by another bug before purging CDN caching on the favicon assets, but that's done now.

Comment: @AdamLear It is fixed now, thanks!

Comment: @BernardoDuarte Glad to hear it. Thanks for the report!