# Wrong icon showing up in inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode, global-inbox

*This is basically the same issue as [Wrong site icon appearing in my inbox and profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396630/wrong-site-icon-appearing-in-my-inbox-and-profile-page), but that post has been tagged as `status-completed` so I'm not sure whether a new post is required or not.
If this is too redundant, I apologize, and feel free to close this post.*

For some days, instead of the [japanese.stackexchange.com](https://japanese.stackexchange.com) icon, the [3dprinting.stackexchange.com/](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com) has been showing up next to my actions related to the former:

[image]

The post: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76800/conjugation-with-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-and-%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae/76813#76813

This might be related to the dark mode since the author of that other question uses it too.
I also notice that the icons that are mixed up are different for them and for me.

Comment: This is often a CSS sprite deployment bug. If dark mode has a separate CSS sprite then it could well be that it’s only visible in dark mode. You could try switching modes to see if light mode has the same or a similar issue?

Comment: (I don’t see the issue myself but that just means that the icons for the sites I have items for in my inbox have the right locations in the CSS sprites; I don’t have any Japanese Language messages).

Comment: Looks like you're right, I'm only having that issue on stackoverflow.com where I use the dark mode; on other sites, I'm using the light mode (or there's no dark mode at all?), and the japanese.stackexchange.com icon properly shows up.

Comment: Only Stack Overflow has a dark mode theme.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. Anyway, I just switched it on/off to confirm that, and it indeed only happens with the dark mode

Answer (score 7):

Something is goofy with the sprite order on dark mode. Looking into it!

Comment: At least the sprite order being goofy is consistent across all modes ...